# Uploading multiple files with dropzone js plugin and session security: no parallel uploads?

Tags: php, session, file-upload

I'm using the dropzone.js plugin (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) which allows for drag n drop file uploading. Except for the one required parameter of an upload URL and parallelUploads (see below), I am using only the default values for Dropzone.

The site also uses passwords and sessions like this http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL to enforce user security.

The "problem" I have is that the post_file.php doesn't seem to be catching all of the uploads when parallelUploads is more than 1 (its 2 by default).  post_file.php has a login_check at the top to make sure the file being uploaded is from a valid user and to get the userID.  Disabling the login_check makes the problem go away, but obviously this isn't a solution.

Why would parallel uploads be a problem for the server side?  Is it messing up the session mojo?  Any ideas for a solution?

Its not mission critical that there be parallel uploads, but it'd be nice so smaller files could pass one larger file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after only 2 days!

The `sec_session_start` function contains `session_regenerate_id(true);`.  In order to prevent unauthorized uploads, the upload page has session authentication.  So when multiple files were being uploaded simultaneously, the session info was being regenerated but it wasn't being propagated in time, so only one or maybe two files would get in.

I realized the issue while debugging multiple parallel ajax requests.  (The ajax page uses the same authorization checks.)

Not wanting to completely get rid of the regeneration, I added a parameter $ajax=0 to the `sec_session_start`.  This way I could leave untouched all the other (non-parallel activity) pages. I changed the line to `if (!$ajax) session_regenerate_id(true);`.  Now on the parallel activity pages (ajax and file upload) I call it as `sec_session_start(1)`.

Problem solved for both ajax and uploads.